# Broken packages during installation of RabbitMQ

Tags: installation, rabbitmq, console, ubuntu-22.04

I'm stuck during installing RabbitMQ server by following guide: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/4946

After a try of installing Erlang packages

```
sudo apt-get install -y erlang-base \
                        erlang-asn1 erlang-crypto erlang-eldap erlang-ftp erlang-inets \
                        erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon erlang-parsetools erlang-public-key \
                        erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssl \
                        erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tftp erlang-tools erlang-xmerl
```

i get following error:

```
# The following packages have unmet dependencies:
# erlang-crypto : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it can't be installed
# E: Unable to fix errors: you have broken packages.
```

I haven't find any solution on the internet, which can help me :(

How to install this necessary package?